# Pegar tamanho arquivo em Delphi mesmo estando em uso

Tags: arquivo, delphi-7

Preciso pegar o tamanho de um arquivo pelo delphi 7 porém estou recebendo erro de I/O por que o arquivo está sendo usado. (O arquivo é um .exe e está aberto)

Já tentei os seguintes códigos:

```
function TamanhoDoArquivo(arquivo: string): LongInt;
var
  lArquivo: file of byte;
begin
  with TFileStream.Create(arquivo, fmOpenRead or fmShareExclusive) do
  try
    Result := Size;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

E também:

```
function TamanhoDoArquivo(arquivo: string): LongInt;
var
  lArquivo: file of byte;
begin
  try
    AssignFile(lArquivo, arquivo);
    try
      reset(lArquivo);
      Result := FileSize(lArquivo);
    finally
      CloseFile(lArquivo)
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Showmessage('Erro');
end;
end;
```

Há alguma forma de pegar o tamanho do .exe mesmo que o mesmo esteja aberto? Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function FileSize(const aFilename: String): Int64;
var
    info: TWin32FileAttributeData;
begin
    result := -1;

    if NOT GetFileAttributesEx(PWideChar(aFileName), GetFileExInfoStandard, @info) then
        EXIT;

    result := Int64(info.nFileSizeLow) or Int64(info.nFileSizeHigh shl 32);
end;
```

Fonte: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1642355/4649737)